# With rspec, can I mock an object that is inside the method I am testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have defined the following method:

```
def some_method

  x = x + 1
  y = some_other_method(x)


  x + y
end
```

Now in my rspec spec, can I mock the call to some_other_method for my unit test for some_method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed mock out other methods in a RSpec test. If the two methods you mentioned are inside a class, `Foo`, you would do something like this to make sure that `some_other_method` is called:

```
subject{ Foo.new }
it "should do whatever you're testing" do
  subject.should_receive(:some_other_method).and_return(5)
  subject.some_method
end
```

If you don't need to assert that is was called, just assert the results of `some_method`, you can do something like this instead:

```
subject{ Foo.new }
it "should do whatever you're testing" do
  subject.stub(:some_other_method).and_return(5)
  subject.some_method.should eq(6)
end
```

The above examples assume you're using RSpec 2. If you're using RSpec 1, you'll need to use `stubs` instead of `stub`.

If your methods are defined outside of a class, they're really defined on the class `Object`, so just use `Object` instead of `Foo` in the examples above.

For more information about mocks in RSpec, check out http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks for RSpec 2 or http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/ for RSpec 1.

Comment: The method is in a helper, do I have to do Subject {...} or could I embed it inside the it ".." do block?

Comment: the object I need to stub 'some_other_method' returns and object that has 2 properties   .age and .height   so how can I do that, 'and_returns(5)' is only returning a single value without an object with properties.

Comment: You don't need to do subject, it's just the way I generally format tests. If it's a helper test, I think you'll need to stub it on the `helper` proxy that RSpec gives you.

Comment: You can return either an instance of the object it should be returning, or you can return a test double with that responds to the methods you need. In future, you'll probably get better answers the first time if you make your example more like the actual problem you're trying to solve -- include the helper module and show that it's acting on a model or whatever.

Comment: btw stub doesnt' work for me, 'stubs' does.  rspec version issue?

Comment: Probably. My example was based on RSpec 2, if you're pre Rails3, you're probably using RSpec 1. In that case, docs are at http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/partial_mocks.html

Comment: sorry for not describing the issue, I just realized the problem domain was a bit trickier